# Record A video with a dynamic text on each frame using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, swift4, avassetwriter

I am trying to record a video and add a dynamic text on that, and then save that to PhotoGallery. When i am saving that File, only video file is getting saved without Audio, And I am still not sure how i am gonna add a text label on each frame.

Following is my VideoWriter and controller Code.

**VideoWriter.swift**

```
import Foundation
import AVFoundation
import PhotosUI
import AssetsLibrary

class VideoWriter : NSObject{
    var fileWriter: AVAssetWriter!
    var videoInput: AVAssetWriterInput!
    var audioInput: AVAssetWriterInput!
    var fileUrl: URL!
    let fileManager = FileManager.default

    init(height:Int, width:Int, channels:Int = 2, samples:Float64 = 44100){
        let directory = VideoWriter.directoryForNewVideo()
        fileUrl = directory.appendingPathComponent(UUID().uuidString + "video.mp4")
        fileWriter = try? AVAssetWriter(outputURL: fileUrl as URL, fileType: AVFileType.mov)

        let videoOutputSettings: Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = [
            AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecType.h264 as AnyObject,
            AVVideoWidthKey : width as AnyObject,
            AVVideoHeightKey : height as AnyObject
        ];
        videoInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: .video, outputSettings: videoOutputSettings)
        videoInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = true
        fileWriter.add(videoInput)

        let audioOutputSettings: Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = [
            AVFormatIDKey : Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC) as AnyObject,
            AVNumberOfChannelsKey : channels as AnyObject,
            AVSampleRateKey : samples as AnyObject,
            AVEncoderBitRateKey : 128000 as AnyObject
        ]
        audioInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: .audio, outputSettings: audioOutputSettings)
        audioInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = true
        fileWriter.add(audioInput)
    }

    func write(sample: CMSampleBuffer, isVideo: Bool){
        if CMSampleBufferDataIsReady(sample) {
            if fileWriter.status == AVAssetWriterStatus.unknown {
                let startTime = CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sample)
                fileWriter.startWriting()
                fileWriter.startSession(atSourceTime: startTime)
            }
            if fileWriter.status == AVAssetWriterStatus.failed {
                return
            }
            if isVideo {
                if videoInput.isReadyForMoreMediaData {
                    videoInput.append(sample)
                }
            }else{
                if audioInput.isReadyForMoreMediaData {
                    audioInput.append(sample)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static func directoryForNewVideo() -> URL {
        let videoDir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first?.appendingPathComponent("videos")
        return videoDir!
    }

    // MARK: - Helpers
    func saveVideoToLibrary(videoURL:URL) {
        let videoLibrary = PHPhotoLibrary.shared()
        videoLibrary.performChanges({
            PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: videoURL)
        })
    }

    func finish(callback: @escaping () -> ()){
        fileWriter.finishWriting(completionHandler: callback)
        self.saveVideoToLibrary(videoURL: self.fileUrl)
        if fileManager.isDeletableFile(atPath: fileUrl.absoluteString){
            do{
                try fileManager.removeItem(atPath: fileUrl.absoluteString)
            }
            catch{
                print("Error")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**CameraViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class CameraViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate, AVCaptureAudioDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {

    @IBAction func switchCamera(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {self.switchCamera()}
    @IBAction func backButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) { self.backToHome()}
    @IBOutlet var bgImage: UIImageView!
    @IBAction func recording(_ sender: Any) {self.startCapture()}
    @IBOutlet var camPreview: UIView!
    let outputSettings: Dictionary<CFString, Any> = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA]
    var assetWriterInput:AVAssetWriterInput!

    let cameraButton = UIView()
    let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    let movieOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
    let audioOutput = AVCaptureAudioDataOutput()
    var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!
    var activeInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput!
    var outputURL: URL!
    var currentCameraPosition: CameraPosition?
    var frontCameraInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput?
    var frontCamera: AVCaptureDevice?
    var rearCamera: AVCaptureDevice?
    var rearCameraInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput?
    var videoWriter:VideoWriter!
    var isRecording = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if setupSession() {
            setupPreview()
            self.bgImage.isHidden = true
            startSession()
            self.videoWriter = VideoWriter(height: Int(self.camPreview.frame.height), width: Int(self.camPreview.frame.width))
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
//        self.write(image: UIImage(named: "STANDARD")!, toBuffer: sampleBuffer)
        let isVideo:Bool = output == movieOutput
        self.videoWriter.write(sample: sampleBuffer, isVideo: isVideo)
    }


    func write(image overlayImage:UIImage, toBuffer sample:CMSampleBuffer){
        if let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sample){
            CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))
            var bitmapInfo: UInt32 = CGBitmapInfo.byteOrder32Little.rawValue
            bitmapInfo |= CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedFirst.rawValue & CGBitmapInfo.alphaInfoMask.rawValue
            let context = CGContext(data: CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBuffer), width: CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBuffer), height: CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuffer), bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(pixelBuffer), space: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo)
            context?.draw(overlayImage.cgImage!, in: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: overlayImage.size.width, height: overlayImage.size.height))
            CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))
        }
    }

    func switchCamera(){
        // Make sure the device has more than 1 camera.
        if AVCaptureDevice.devices(for: AVMediaType.video).count > 1 {
            // Check which position the active camera is.
            var newPosition: AVCaptureDevice.Position!
            if activeInput.device.position == AVCaptureDevice.Position.back {
                newPosition = AVCaptureDevice.Position.front
            } else {
                newPosition = AVCaptureDevice.Position.back
            }
            // Get camera at new position.
            var newCamera: AVCaptureDevice!
            let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devices(for: AVMediaType.video)
            for device in devices {
                if (device as AnyObject).position == newPosition {
                    newCamera = device
                }
            }
            // Create new input and update capture session.
            do {
                let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: newCamera)
                captureSession.beginConfiguration()
                // Remove input for active camera.
                captureSession.removeInput(activeInput)
                // Add input for new camera.
                if captureSession.canAddInput(input) {
                    captureSession.addInput(input)
                    activeInput = input
                } else {
                    captureSession.addInput(activeInput)
                }
                captureSession.commitConfiguration()
            } catch {
                print("Error switching cameras: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }

    func backToHome(){
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as! FrontPageTableViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }

    // MARK: - Setup session and preview
    func setupSession() -> Bool {
        self.assetWriterInput =  AVAssetWriterInput.init(mediaType: .video, outputSettings: outputSettings as [String : Any])
        captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.medium
        // Setup Camera
        let camera = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: AVMediaType.video)
        do {
            let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: camera!)
            if captureSession.canAddInput(input) {
                captureSession.addInput(input)
                activeInput = input
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error setting device video input: \(error)")
            return false
        }
        // Setup Microphone
        let microphone = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: AVMediaType.audio)
        do {
            let micInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: microphone!)
            if captureSession.canAddInput(micInput){
                captureSession.addInput(micInput)
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error setting device audio input: \(error)")
            return false
        }
        // Movie output
        self.movieOutput.videoSettings = [
            kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as AnyHashable as! String : Int(kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange)
        ]
        let captureSessionQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "CameraSessionQueue", attributes: [])
        self.movieOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: captureSessionQueue)
        if captureSession.canAddOutput(movieOutput) {
            captureSession.addOutput(movieOutput)
        }
        if captureSession.canAddOutput(audioOutput){
            captureSession.addOutput(audioOutput)
        }

        self.captureSession.commitConfiguration()
        return true
    }

    func setupPreview() {
        // Configure previewLayer
        camPreview.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.camPreview.frame.height)
        previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        previewLayer.frame = camPreview.bounds
        previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
        camPreview.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
    }

    //MARK:- Camera Session
    func startSession() {
        if !captureSession.isRunning {
            videoQueue().async {
                self.captureSession.startRunning()
            }
        }
    }

    func stopSession() {
        if captureSession.isRunning {
            videoQueue().async {
                self.captureSession.stopRunning()
            }
        }
    }

    func videoQueue() -> DispatchQueue {
        return DispatchQueue.main
    }

    // setup URL
    func tempURL() -> URL? {
        let directory = NSTemporaryDirectory() as NSString
        if directory != "" {
            let path = directory.appendingPathComponent(NSUUID().uuidString + ".mp4")
            return URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
        }
        return nil
    }

    func setupCaptureMode(_ mode: Int) {
        // Video Mode
    }


    // Camera Orientation
    func currentVideoOrientation() -> AVCaptureVideoOrientation {
        var orientation: AVCaptureVideoOrientation
        switch UIDevice.current.orientation {
        case .portrait:
            orientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
        case .landscapeRight:
            orientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.landscapeLeft
        case .portraitUpsideDown:
            orientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portraitUpsideDown
        default:
            orientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.landscapeRight
        }
        return orientation
    }

    @objc func startCapture() {
        self.startRecording()
    }

    // StartRecording
    func startRecording() {
        if !self.isRecording{
            self.isRecording = true
            let connection = movieOutput.connection(with: AVMediaType.video)
            if (connection?.isVideoOrientationSupported)! {
                connection?.videoOrientation = currentVideoOrientation()
            }
            if (connection?.isVideoStabilizationSupported)! {
                connection?.preferredVideoStabilizationMode = AVCaptureVideoStabilizationMode.auto
            }
            let device = activeInput.device
            if (device.isSmoothAutoFocusSupported) {
                do {
                    try device.lockForConfiguration()
                    device.isSmoothAutoFocusEnabled = false
                    device.unlockForConfiguration()
                } catch {
                    print("Error setting configuration: \(error)")
                }
            }
        }else{
            self.isRecording = false
            self.stopRecording()
        }

    }

    func stopRecording() {
        self.captureSession.stopRunning()
        self.videoWriter.finish(callback: {})
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let vc = segue.destination as! VideoPlayback
        vc.videoURL = sender as! URL
    }
}

enum CameraPosition {
    case front
    case rear
}

extension CameraViewController {
    enum CameraControllerError: Swift.Error {
        case captureSessionAlreadyRunning
        case captureSessionIsMissing
        case inputsAreInvalid
        case invalidOperation
        case noCamerasAvailable
        case unknown
    }
}
```

I need help for two things in this code -

**1)** Save Video with Audio

**2)** Add a timer or any random text on each frame.

Comment: did you find a solution to add text on each frame?

Comment: no answer yet? damn :O